# Java and JS: storing results as a Java variable

Tags: java, javascript, dom, cross-browser

I am trying to compare browser differences by using a single url and comparing all properties as well as coordinates between 2 browsers. I know I can get all the elements using `document.getElementsByTagName(*);` but how would I store the results of this script in a Java variable (List?). Please keep in mind I'm very new to JS.

Other info: I'm using WebDriver to implement js like so:

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("var all = document.getElementsByTagName(*);");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> elements =  (List<WebElement>) js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName(*);");
```

See [JavascriptExecutor API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

> - *For an HTML element, this method returns a WebElement*
> - *For an array, return a List with each object following the rules above. We support nested lists.*

[EDIT] Casr

Comment: It says--- Incompatible types: Required: java.util.List found: java.lang.Object. So I don't think this will work. but I think this will:
        ArrayList<Object> elements = new ArrayList();
        elements.add(js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName(*);"));

thanks!